# Why Python 2.7 creates processes for threading.Thread

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I run code on ARM Raspbian linux, Python 2.7.13 and amd64 Gentoo linux, Python 2.7.14

I have a function

```
import threading
def r() : 
    s = 1
    while True:
        s = s + 1
```

Then I create thread for this function

```
t = threading.Thread(target=r)
t.start()
```

And after that in htop I can see another process spawned (with its own PID)! And processing.Thread documentation says:

> CPython implementation detail: In CPython, due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once (even though certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome this limitation).If you want your application to make better use of the computational resources of multi-core machines, you are advised to use multiprocessing.

Why is this behavior differs from documentation?

Comment: Can you post the output of `htop` as well? AFAIK `threading` should not start another process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's actually an OS thing: processes and threads do not differ that much on Linux. Htop will list all the separate threads as if they were processes. [See this Unix Stack Exchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10362/why-does-htop-show-more-process-than-ps) for more info.

Comment: Setting "display threads in different color" in htop can help

Comment: Thank you, that was an issue